# Allowed memory size exhausted - Where is the memory leak?

Tags: php

I'm practicing code on a website. The instructions are: Write a method that takes an array of consecutive (increasing) letters as input and that returns the missing letter in the array.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function find_missing_letter($arr) {
    $inputArr = [];
    $ndArr = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        array_push($inputArr, ord($arr[$i]));
    }
    for($z = current($inputArr); $z <= end($inputArr); $z++) {
        array_push($ndArr, $z);
    }
    $result = chr(implode("",array_diff($ndArr, $inputArr)));
        return $result;
    }
    find_missing_letter(["a","c", "d"]); //returns "b"
```

It works just fine on phpsandbox, but on the coding website I get this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

I did some research and found out that it must be a memory leak. I was hoping someone here could explain to me where in my code is the memory leak, as I'm really eager to learn.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any possible memory leak in this code. It consistently uses 393216 bytes of RAM (0.29% of your server's limit) when I run it. I strongly suspect something else is going on. Is this running on some sort of super-cheap or free hosting?

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for your reply! I run it on CodeWars

Comment: In that case, I strongly suspect CodeWars runs your code *within* a bunch of other code, and you should report this to their support team.

Comment: to minimize the mem usage, dont put functions inside loops, only pre-counted variables. like `for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)` : first you count `$count = count($arr);` then you loop: `for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)` otherwise i think it counts it every loop.

Comment: It executes the first part once, the 2nd and 3rd parts on every iteration of a for loop.  So yes it counts it every iteration.

Comment: Works fine for me [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/729ac46c30daa021fb2881eee466ef757248cde3)

Comment: The error notice might also contain line number. Could you check which line is it?

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks it was the line that refers to: return $result;
Probably some problem with their server, as now, after 40 minutes of brainstorming, it finally works. Thanks again!